# How to map in node.js using a returned database object with a where clause?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

Newer to Node and I'm getting this error when I switch the query to have a where clause...

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I am struggling with map and merging with other data.  My query is returning the correct data excluded.  Maybe I should get everything and filter it?  Here's the code.

```
export async function generateWorkoutWeeks(weeks, startingDate) {
  const Op = require('sequelize').Op;
  state.date = startingDate
  try{
  state.movements = await Movement.findAll({ where: { VideoURL: {[Op.not]: null}} }).then(movements =>
    movements.map(movement => ({
      ...movement,
      equipment: movement.equipment.map(e => e.id),
      muscles: movement.muscles.map(m => m.id),
      variations: movement.variations.map(v => v.id),
    }
    )),
  )
  }catch (e) { console.log(movement)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be because some `movement`'s don't have the necessary children and they're undefined.

```
  equipment: movement.equipment.map(e => e.id),
  muscles: movement.muscles.map(m => m.id),
  variations: movement.variations.map(v => v.id),
```

In the above code, if either `equipment` or `muscles` or `variations` is undefined, it will throw the error you're getting.

So, try to change it to this:

```
  equipment: movement.equipment && movement.equipment.map(e => e.id),
  muscles: movement.muscles && movement.muscles.map(m => m.id),
  variations: movement.variations && movement.variations.map(v => v.id),
```

Comment: Oh, but looking further at the returned object equipment, muscles, and variations are undefined...

Comment: Yeah if they're undefined, undefined will be returned. If you want an empty array you can do it like this: `equipment: movement.equipment ? movement.equipment.map(e => e.id) : [],`

Comment: hmmm originally when the findall had this settting include: [{ all: true }] they did have data.  I thought my where clause would just be a subset of all the data I was getting at first.

Comment: So if I do... .findAll({ include: [{ all: true }], where: { VideoURL: {[Op.not]: null}} })  all the data shows up.  Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you do this -

```
state.movements = await Movement.findAll({ where: { VideoURL: { [Op.not]: null } } });
console.log(typeof(movements),movements)
state.movements.then(movements =>
    movements.map(movement => ({
        ...movement,
        equipment: movement.equipment.map(e => e.id),
        muscles: movement.muscles.map(m => m.id),
        variations: movement.variations.map(v => v.id),
    }))
);
```